# How do i limit the number of rows updated in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, subquery, limit, offset

I am trying to update records in customer table by limiting them to n number of records but i am having an error when i am using offset and limit keywords.

Where do i put

```
offset 0 limit 1
```

in update statement sub query as the sub query is like:

```
update customer set name = 'sample name' where customer_id in (142, 143, 144, 145 offset 0 limit 1);
```

When i tried executing update statement above, i get an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "offset"
>
> Note: limit does not have to be 1, it can be any number and same is true for offset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offset` and `limit` work on rows, not on a list.

You can transform the `in()` clause to use a subquery that return a row from each of your input

update customer

```
set name = 'sample name' 
where customer_id in (select unnest(array[142, 143, 144, 145]) offset 0 limit 1);
```